# How to access prototype method

Tags: javascript

```
function Person1(){
  this.name='Person1 Name';
  this.Age='Person1 Age';
  this.Sex='Person1 Sex';

}

Person1.prototype.getInfo=function(){
  return this.name;
}


var Person2=Object.create(Person1.prototype);

console.log(Person2.getInfo());
```

I want output as Person1 Name by Inheritance, What are the ways to achieve it. Here I would like to know what Person2 contains? what are the different 
Ways?

Comment: `Person2.prototype.getInfo()`?

Comment: Person2.prototype.getInfo() It do nothing just return nothing

Comment: of course, because Person2 has no name property. `Person2.name = 'Person2 Name'`; then `Person2.getInfo()`

Comment: What is correct Syntax to achieve this. Please Help.

Comment: you're using inheritance all wrong - look at examples in [Object.create](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) documentation, and [inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) documentation if you want to learn how to do things in javscript ... for example, not once do you use the `new` keyword in your code, so not sure what you actually expect

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX. you understand my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person1(){
  this.name='Person1 Name';
  this.Age='Person1 Age';
  this.Sex='Person1 Sex';

}

Person1.prototype.getInfo=function(){
  return this.name;
}


var Person2= new Person1();

console.log(Person2.getInfo());
```

Comment: I want to achieve inheritance. so how to do using Object.create(Person1.prototype);

Comment: `var Person2=Object.create(Person1.prototype);`  will inherit from `Person1.prototype` . but then it does not have members called `name, age and sex`.  in the case of `var Person2= new Person1();` , the new object created (`Person2`) is still inherited from `Person1.prototype`  and it also has `name, age and sex`.

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.